# Same C# desktop app doesnt connect to a SQL SERVER 2008R2 in some PCs in a LAN

Tags: c#, sql-server, desktop-application, remote-server

I have several desktop c# apps running in all PCs in a LAN. The apps connect to a SQL SERVER 2008R2 installed in a local LAN server running WIN2012R2.

In almost all PCs the apps work fine, but there are some of them (2) where the apps don't work. The resulting error is a "SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 – Error Locating Server/Instance Specified".

The connection string in all apps are like this: "Data Source=MY-SERVER\SQLSERVER2008R2;Initial Catalog=my_database;User ID=sa;Password=my_pass" where MY-SERVER is the server network name and SQLSERVER2008R2 is the name of the SQL instance running in server.

All PCs are in the same workgroup. We have PCs running the apps ok with Win 7, Win 10 and Win 8. One of the problematic PC is running Win7 and the other is running Win 8.

From the problematic PCs I can ping and telnet to server ip port 1433 without problem, also I can run a SQL Server Management Studio and can connect ok with the SQL Server and work with the databases. Besides I have several Excel VBA apps that connect to the SQL Server and also work.

In short, all PCs in the LAN (+10) run the same desktop and Excel apps. All have the SQL Server Management Studio installed. All Excel apps work in all PCs, SSMS works also in all PCs, telnet and ping work in all PCs and the desktop apps work in all except those 2 PCs.

I also have checked firewalls in server and in the clients machines, I have changed the conn string from name server to the ip and port. I have reinstalled ODBC drivers in both PCs and nothing.

Here is a sample of my code

```
internal void accessingDatabase()
{
            string query="Select * from my_table";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=MY-SERVER\\SQLSERVER2008R2;Initial Catalog=my_database;User ID=sa;Password=my_pass";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
}
```

The exception raises at conn.Open();

Any clues?

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: If you set up an empty network share on the same server, is it accessible from the problematic PCs?

Comment: PIng the servername, do a traceroute -d

Comment: @DiskJunky The problematics PCs can access any PCs in the network, for example all shared folders in all PCs. Also they can access the databases at the server via SSMS

Comment: @Namphibian I already did that, ping server from PCs and also telnet using the sql server port 1433

Comment: Solved!! the problem was in another part of the code, not related with anything in the network nor the sql connection. The app uses the names of the PCs to establish the sql connection and there was a collision between two names.